# Python MySQLdb change string encoding

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, collation, gensim

I believe my issue is that python does not play nicely with the character encoding of a column in a SQL table:

```
| column | varchar(255) | latin1_swedish_ci | YES  |     | NULL              |                             | select,insert,update,references |    |
```

The above shows the output for this column. It has type `varchar(255)` and has encoding `latin1_swedish_ci.`

Now when I try to make python play with this data, I am getting the following error:

```
 dictionary = gs.corpora.Dictionary(tweets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.add_documents(documents)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py", line 97, in add_documents
    _ = self.doc2bow(document, allow_update=True) # ignore the result, here we only care about updating token ids
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py", line 121, in doc2bow
    document = sorted(utils.to_utf8(token) for token in document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py", line 121, in <genexpr>
    document = sorted(utils.to_utf8(token) for token in document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 164, in any2utf8
    return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors).encode('utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

`gs` is the [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) topic modeling library. I believe that the problem is that gensim requires unicode encodings.

1. How can I change the character encoding (collation?) for this column in my database?
2. Is there an alternative solution?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your MYSQLdb python library doesn't know it's supposed to encode to utf8

and is encoding to the default python system-defined charset latin1.

When you connect() to your database, pass the  `charset='utf8'`

parameter. This should also make a manual `SET NAMES`

Comment: Applying this solution, I found out that the result strings become `Unicode` instead of `utf8`. I explain why this happens in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53665616/3692177).

Answer (score 2):

For question 1, you'll need to use

```
alter table t 
modify col varchar(255) 
character set utf8
collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

I don't know about question 2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @saudi_Dev's solution, with MySQLdb v1.2.5. The table I query has been created with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`. Even so, before trying @saudi_Dev's solution, `cursor.fetchall()` returned strings in `latin1` for some reason. After using `charset=utf8` parameter, `cursor.fetchall()` returns strings as `Unicode` (technically not `utf8`) instead of `latin1`.

But I have seen in http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html that you can also pass the parameter `use_unicode=False`. This happens because, according to the User's Guide from the link I posted, using `charset` parameter implies `use_unicode=True`.